# If $\mathcal O(G)$ is semi-simple then $G$ is finite.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-groups, representation-theory

I want to show that if $\mathcal O(G)$ is semi-simple, for $G$ an affine algebraic group and $\mathcal O(G)$ its coordinate ring, then $G$ is finite but I don't really see how to do that. I tought maybe use Artin-Wedderburn's theorem to deduce that $\mathcal O(G)$ is a finite dimensionnal $k$-vector space (where $k$ is an algebrically closed fields) and then use the correspondence between coordinate rings and affine algebraic sets $G \cong \text{Hom}_{\text{Alg}_k} (\mathcal O(G), k) \subset \mathcal O(G)^* =  \text{Hom}_{k} (\mathcal O(G), k)$ but I don't know how to conclude that $G$ has to be finite from here. Is it the right way ? Does anyone know how to do that ?

Comment: Is this true? The multiplicative group has coordinate ring $k[x, x^{-1}]$ which is $\mathbb{Z}$-dimensional, but decomposes into a direct sum of simple representations (agreeing with the grading on $k[x, x^{-1}]$).

Comment: It is an exercice from my representation theory course, so I think it is.

Comment: @Joppy: presumably the OP means semisimple as a ring, not as a $G$-representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Artin-Wedderburn as you suggest will work. If $\mathcal{O}(G)$ is a semisimple commutative algebra over an algebraically closed field $k$ then Artin-Wedderburn implies that it's a finite direct product of field extensions of $k$, which are either equal to $k$ or transcendental. Since $G$ is an affine algebraic group $\mathcal{O}(G)$ must be finitely generated as a $k$-algebra which implies (by the Nullstellensatz) that the transcendental extensions can't occur, so $\mathcal{O}(G)$ is a finite direct product of copies of $k$.

I don't know exactly what you mean by "finite" here. You might just mean that the set of $k$-points $G(k)$ is finite, which is clear from here since the number of $k$-points of a finite direct product $\prod_{i=1}^n k$ is exactly $n$ (exercise).  The standard definition of "finite" in the context of affine group schemes, as far as I know, is that $\mathcal{O}(G)$ is finitely generated as a $k$-module, which is also clear here.